# How to use IF statement in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT title, int(durationMins / 60) AS Hours, (durationMins - 60) AS Minutes
FROM Movie
ORDER BY int(durationMins / 60) DESC, (durationMins - 60) DESC;
```

I am trying to make a program to separate how long a film is in minutes into hours and minutes, however there is an issue with this. If a film is exactly 2 hours, or 3 hours.... etc. the value for minutes will equal 60. How do you make an if statement for when durationMin-60=60 to equal 0?

I am using Microsoft Access 2013, any other questions are welcome and help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not need `IF` logic here. You can use [Mod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator) operator to get 0 in your case. Try below query

```
SELECT title, int(durationMins/60) AS Hours, (durationMins Mod 60) AS Minutes
FROM Movie
ORDER BY int(durationMins/60) DESC , (durationMins Mod 60) DESC;
```

Access has [IIF()](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) function for ***`IF`*** logic to implement.

[image]